# Trouble with NameError in IDLE - Python

Tags: python, function, nameerror

got some trouble with my selfmade code.

```
def even(a, b):
    f = []
    while a <= b:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            f.append(a)
        a = a + 1
    return f;
```

When i'm tryin to call it from the shell it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
even(0,200)
NameError: name 'even' is not defined.
```

I think it's not a really tricky problem, but can u help my anyway?
Thank you up front.
Cheers

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: It is likely an issue elsewhere, nothing here is immediately wrong.

Comment: Did you click `run` from your IDE? Because it would seem you just wrote the code in your IDE and then tried calling the function from your shell without running it

Comment: OMG. Just ran the module and now it's working .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Are you indenting your function correctly and how are you calling your function? the following code works:

```
def even(a, b):
    f = []
    while a <= b:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            f.append(a)
        a = a + 1
    return f;

print(even(2,3))
#output: [2]
```

Notice the indentation and the fact that even is being called after it is defined.

Edit: I notice you've gotten it working, now would be a good time to refacter some parts of your function i.e. give the variable f a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it from your shell, you would want to:

1. enter `python` into shell, to start your python interpreter
2. enter `from <your-code's-filename.py> import even`

then you can use the function as you tried: `even(0,200)`

But you can also just run it from within IDLE like Wright suggests.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Just ran it within IDLE and it worked